# Can I show a modal view from another modal view

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller

I'm developing an iOS application with latest SDK.

This app has a `UITabBarController` and, from one of its `UIViewController` I want to show `viewController1` as a modal view.

From `viewController1` and want to show `viewController2`.

My question is: Can I show an `UIViewController` as a modal view from another modal view?

Comment: What you're asking doesn't really make sense. Try re-writing it so it's more clear as to what you want.

Comment: Also, posting sample code never hurt anybody :)

Comment: @jsksma2 Don't worry. Dilip has answered my question.

Comment: So... accept his answer.

Comment: I can't accept his answer. I have to wait 1 minute. Do you know how StackOverflow works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can....Using this code....

Put this code in FirstViewController.

```
ViewController2 *ViewController2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:ViewController2 animated:YES];
```